# Error when trying to encrypt a PDF with itext: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s

Tags: encryption, jakarta-ee, itext

I have a jee application where I generate a pdf and show it to the user on the browser. I have the request to protect the pdf for printing, so the user can´t make any other use of the document except reading. I am using itext 5 and I tried to encrypt the document but I get an error: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

I looked at some examples to encrypt, even in the book for itext5, but I am can´t fix that error. I also looked at some solutions to my problem, some say that is a dependencies problem, maybe duplicated but I still can´t find where, because I dont even have the bouncycastle added to my pom.

This is an extract of my pom.xml of web module.

```
<properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <itext.version>5.5.13</itext.version>
    </properties>

    <dependecies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

The code I am trying to run is the next:

public void crearPDFconTextoHTML(String nombreArchivo, String texto) {
        try {
            String dirCarpetaTemp = directorio();//Creo el directorio temporal sin los archivos
            String dirFinalArchivo = dirCarpetaTemp + nombreArchivo;//Directorio completo del archivo
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirFinalArchivo);
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            String USER_PASS = "Hello123";
            String OWNER_PASS = "Owner123";
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            writer.setEncryption(USER_PASS.getBytes(), OWNER_PASS.getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
            document.setMarginMirroring(true);
            document.open();

            Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph();
            parrafo = convertirHtmlConFormatoAParrafoPdfOld(parrafo, texto);
//            parrafo = convertirTexto(parrafo, texto);

            parrafo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            document.add(parrafo);

            document.close();//cierro el documento
            writer.close();//cierro la escritura

            setNombreArchivo(nombreArchivo);//Agregar el nombre archivo final a la dependencia
//            OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirCarpetaTemp + nombreArchivo);//Crear archivo final
//            PdfTempUtil.doMerge(listPdfs, fos);//Combinar pdfs que se agregaron en la lista
            generarLinksAccesoAlPdf();//Generar la url que se mostrará en la lista
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

The dependencies should be fine and the encryption should work so the user can´t print the pdf when he open it.

Answer (score 1):

> The dependencies should be fine [...]

No the problem are the dependencies. This might not be direct dependencies but [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) - which are dependencies of dependencies (we are talking of children, grandchildren and grand-grand children [...] here to make a comparison)
iText 5.5.13 needs Bouncy Castle version 1.49:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
```

Your primefaces has an older iText version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

which in turn fetches

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>138</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>138</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>138</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Check your dependencies (in your EAR) and see that you have the correct bouncy castle version. Sometimes even your app server brings one along. If you found the culprit then add an `<exclusion>` section to your pom...

Comment: ¡I added version 2.1.7 with maven and it works!, the bad thing is I have been already using the version 5, so I need to figure out if I have to change some of my code to work with this version 2. By the way, I dont understand why primefaces didnt uploaded to the version 5, considering that even 5 is old and 7 is the actual version.

Comment: The short version: This might be due to licensing issues. iText 2.X was usable in commercial environments (without paying) but 5.X or 7.X are AGPL so they aren't. One alternative might be OpenPDF a fork of 2.X...